# Auto grow of column with for hierarchy not working in SSRS 2016

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016

I have a SSRS-2012 report with a hierarchical structure of positions.
For a better recognition of the hierarchy, the child elements are more or less indented depending on the depth in the structure. The lower the level, the higher the indentation.

[image: Hierarchy indention]

In SSRS-2012, if the column text, including indentation, is larger than the column width, then the column width automatically increases to fit all content in the cell.

[image: SSRS 2012 initial column width]

[image: SSRS 2012 growing column width]

[image: SSRS 2012 growing column width]

This is not the case in SSRS-2016. The column width remains constant and the content of the cell is wraped over several rows if the column is too narrow.

[image: SSRS 2016 wrapped column]

Only if there is not enough space, the column will also get wider in 2016.
It is the same report just deployed to SSRS-2012 and SSRS-2016.
CanGrow is set to true is both variants because ist is the same report.
TargetServerVersion for SSRS-2016 doesn't matter, "SQL Server 2008 R2, 2012 or 2014" and "SQL Server 2016 or later" produced the same result.

[Demo project for SSDT 2017](https://www.mediafire.com/file/r2j4843qpmf6yfr/MatrixTest.zip/file)

Is this a bug or a feature of SSRS-2016 or am I missing a settings option?

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but is `CanGrow` set to true on the data row AND the header row?  Might not make a difference, but it could be as simple as that...

Comment: CanGrow is set to true on the data row and the header